# Como comparar 2 valores com YUP

Tags: react, validation, yup

Bom dia eu tenho uma validação para fazer com o yup, e preciso fazer com que o intervalo inicial não seja maior que o intervalo final, Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso? tentei passar as variáveis do mesmo em ambos os campos do schema, mas não deu certo.Segue o código:

````
const schema = yup.object().shape({
intervalo_inicial: yup.number().test('len',
  'Valor deve ser maior que 0', v => v > 0.00 && v < 100.00).required(),
intervalo_final: yup.number().test('len',
  'Valor deve ser menor que 100', v1 => v1 < 100.00 && v1 > 0.00).required(),
});```
````

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [`.ref()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#yuprefpath-string-options--contextprefix-string--ref) e [`.moreThan()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#numbermorethanmin-number--ref-message-string--function-schema):

```
let schema = Yup.object().shape({
  intervalo_inicial: Yup
    .number()
    .required()
    .positive()
    .integer(),
  intervalo_final: Yup.number()
    .required()
    .positive()
    .moreThan(Yup.ref('intervalo_inicial'), "Intervalo final deve ser maior que o inicial")
    .integer(),
});
```